# dynamodb update call failing with non descriptive error

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, amazon-dynamodb

What am i doing wrong here?
The following Update call is failing:

```
await dynamoClient.send(
    new UpdateItemCommand({
      TableName: IMAGE_TABLE_NAME,
      Key: {
        path: key,
      },
      UpdateExpression: "set #url = :url, #size = :size, #etag = :etag",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":url": { S: publicUrl },
        ":size": { S: size },
        ":etag": { S: eTag },
      },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#url": "url",
        "#size": "size",
        "#etag": "etag",
      },
      ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
    })
);
```

with the following message:

```
2022-01-04T07:02:46.912Z    58e4a20d-4631-4d28-b8eb-790be6fd10a9    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
"errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
"reason": {
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
        "    at Object.AttributeValue2.visit (/var/task/index.js:2176:40)",
        "    at serializeAws_json1_0AttributeValue (/var/task/index.js:7416:40)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:7756:18",
        "    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)",
        "    at serializeAws_json1_0Key (/var/task/index.js:7751:36)",
        "    at serializeAws_json1_0UpdateItemInput (/var/task/index.js:8224:64)",
        "    at Object.serializeAws_json1_0UpdateItemCommand (/var/task/index.js:3688:29)",
        "    at serialize (/var/task/index.js:11663:30)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:515:29",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:13099:30"
    ]
},
"promise": {},
"stack": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
    "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)",
    "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
]
```

}

The values are there:

```
console.log("key, eTag, size, publicUrl:");
console.log(key, eTag, size, publicUrl);

# 2022-01-04T07:02:46.712Z  58e4a20d-4631-4d28-b8eb-790be6fd10a9    INFO    images/f796fa32-ed93-451a-b7b6-197b642e25fd/Logo.png af3aaba823d92b492b95695e2545ceda 522215 https://mainstack-imagesgrayhoundbucketimages3b600464-1gabt0s0y3cf0.s3.amazonaws.com/images/f796fa32-ed93-451a-b7b6-197b642e25fd/Logo.png
```

and here is the dynamodb data in the dynamodb (viewing it as JSON):

```
{
  "path": {
    "S": "images/f796fa32-ed93-451a-b7b6-197b642e25fd/Logo.png"
  },
  "filename": {
    "S": "Logo.png"
  },
  "size": {
    "S": ""
  },
  "userId": {
    "S": "f796fa32-ed93-451a-b7b6-197b642e25fd"
  },
  "meta": {
    "M": {
      "uploadedDate": {
        "S": "2022-01-04T07:19:46.095Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "extension": {
    "S": "png"
  },
  "etag": {
    "S": ""
  },
  "url": {
    "S": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that here:

```
new UpdateItemCommand({
      TableName: IMAGE_TABLE_NAME,
      Key: {
        path: key,
      },
```

the value passed to `path` needs to be an [AttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html), e.g. `{ S: key }`, similar to what you've done in `ExpressionAttributeValues`.

```
new UpdateItemCommand({
      TableName: IMAGE_TABLE_NAME,
      Key: {
        path: { S: key },
      },
```

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: Was the error the same? @ArmenB

Comment: actually that worked, I had to pass an empty ExpressionAttributeNames: {}

Comment: here is the sample for others who might see this error: `      const updateItemCommandArgs = {
        TableName: IMAGE_TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
          path: { S: key },
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set url = :url, size = :size, etag = :etag",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":url": { S: publicUrl.toString() },
          ":size": { S: size.toString() },
          ":etag": { S: eTag.toString() },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
      };`